# How to pass a python wordcloud element to svgwrite method to generate a svg of the wordcloud?

Tags: python, python-2.7, svg, svgwrite

I am trying to generate a svg of the word_cloud being formed out of some hardcoded strings(as of now, later these strings will be dynamically generated). 
Below is the Python code to generate word_cloud:

```
from os import path
from wordcloud import WordCloud
d = path.dirname(__file__)
# Read the whole text.
#text = open(path.join(d, 'test.txt')).read()
mytext = ['hello, hi, ibm, pune, hola']
# Generate a word cloud image
wordcloud = WordCloud().generate(text)
import svgwrite
# Display the generated image:
# the matplotlib way:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation='bilinear')
plt.axis("off")
```

Now instead of using plt.show(), I want to pass the wordcloud variable to svgwrite method as below:

```
svg_document = svgwrite.Drawing(filename = "test-svgwrite.svg",profile = 'full')
svg_document.add(svg_document.text(wordcloud,
                                        insert = (210, 110)))
svg_document.tostring()
svg_document.save()
```

However, this created SVG doesn't contain any wordcloud, only the text (shown in below screenshot):
[check the screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snqXm.png)

Answer (score 5):

Facing some issues using matplotlib (which will use raster graphics in combination with wordcloud although it will be saved as ".svg"), i have figured out another way

```
wordcloud = WordCloud()
wordcloud.generate_from_frequencies(frequencies=features)
wordcloud_svg = wordcloud.to_svg(embed_font=True)
f = open("filename.svg","w+")
f.write(wordcloud_svg )
f.close()
```

The embed_font boolean prevented the words from overlapping.
Also you have a lot of freedom modifying wordcloud_svg to change colors, fonts , etc. It has an xml-like structure (print it :) )

Answer (score 2):

I found this while looking to do the same exact thing. I got the same results from svgwrite and wound up using matplotlib's features instead.

In matplotlib's [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend) there is discussion of changing the format the backend uses. When the backend is using SVG format, the plot can be saved as a .svg

In the imports section:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('SVG') #set the backend to SVG
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

After generating the WordCloud

```
fname = "cloud_test"
plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation="bilinear") 
plt.axis("off")
fig = plt.gcf() #get current figure
fig.set_size_inches(10,10)  
plt.savefig(fname, dpi=700)
```

savefig(filename) automatically saves it in SVG format, since that is what the backend is set to.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked fine for me:

```py
word_cloud = WordCloud(margin=10, background_color='white', min_font_size=12, width=800, height=400).generate(words)
# generate plot and save as file in current directory
plt.imshow(word_cloud, interpolation='bilinear')
plt.axis("off")
plt.savefig('word_cloud' + ".svg", dpi=700, format="svg")
plt.close()
```